# JSP Jetty compilation error

Tags: java, jsp, jetty

I am trying run my first jetty. 
`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>page/index.jsp</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My `index.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
            content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Embedding Jettye</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Running Jetty web server from our application!!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

And when i run my application and type proper URL into browser i get:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /runjetty/. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.sendWelcome(DefaultServlet.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:486)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.<init>(Validator.java:515)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1853)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    ... 44 more
```

In `.jsp` file is not any code compilation parts ( excepts 1st line I quess). Have You any ideas how i could fix it ?

Comment: Where is index.jsp located in your web project? (Is it in a directory named 'page' under the root of the webapp?)

Comment: It is in: 
`JettyFromMain/page/index.jsp` where `JettyFromMain` is root dir of application contains directory like `src` `bin`

Comment: There is no issue with your JSP. It compiles fine for me. Check your dependencies. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583103/jsp-compilation-error-on-jetty-9-3-3